# Can't display image in custom keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uiimage, ios8

i'm building custom keyboard for ios 8, so i want to display one image here but it's seems not work.
I really don't know why, here is my code:

```
var img = UIImageView()
img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
img.image = UIImage(named: "interesting.jpg")
self.view.addSubview(img)
```

Nothing appear but if i change to display an UILabel, it's ok.
When i move this code to ViewController image display fine.
I couldn't display image in keyboard area only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this: `UIImage(named: "interesting")` and have the name of the image in the asset catalog be `interesting`

Comment: Though to be clear I don't use swift so I am unsure.